# TypeError: change() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'B1' and 'B2'

Tags: python, multithreading, typeerror

So here is my code.

```
import threading
def change(B1,B2):
        if(B1>B2):
                B2=B1
                B1=0
        else:
                B1=B2
                B2=0
        print(B1,B2)
        threading.Timer(1,change(B1,B2)).start()


change(1,0)
```

I want to see
0 1
1 0
0 1
1 0
...

something like this change every second. However, this shows 0 1 first and shows error. Error message was

```
TypeError: change() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'B1' and 'B2'
```

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but the second argument to `Timer` needs to be a function, not a function call.  Perhaps you mean the second argument to be `lambda: change(B1, B2)`?

Comment: It could also work as `threading.Timer(1, change, (B1,B2)).start()`. That issue doesn't really match up with the exception described though. Are you sure the error you're giving corresponds the the code you show?

Comment: I should point out that right now, you just have infinite recursion with no timer.  threading.Timer will **immediately** evaluate its arguments.  But this makes another call to `change`, which makes another call to `change`... and threading.Timer never gets called.